# How do I create a while loop within a PHP string?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am creating a query using shortcodes ultimate lightbox. But the only way this will work within a regular php page, is to save the data as string. So what I need to do is to create my query but somehow get my results within a string.

Here is what works before I use any kind of php query:

```
 <?php     
 $my_tabs = "<ul class='easybuttons'>
 <li>[su_lightbox type='inline' src='#lightbox1']AT&amp;T[/su_lightbox]</li>
 <li>[su_lightbox type='inline' src='#lightbox2']Sprint[/su_lightbox]</li>
 <li>[su_lightbox type='inline' src='#lightbox3']T-Mobile[/su_lightbox]</li>
 </ul>";

 echo do_shortcode( $my_tabs );
 ?>
```

but I need the ATT, Sprint, T-Mobile to be dynamic. Keep in mind the shortcode will only work if it within a string.

So how can I do a while loop within this string? I tried using an operator but did not work.

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'services', 'category_name' =>  $childid, 'order_by' => 'the_title', 'order' => 'ASC');     

 query_posts($args);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
 $my_tabs .= '<ul class="easybuttons">'; 
 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
 $the_query->the_post();
 $my_tabs .= '<li>[su_lightbox type="inline" src="#lightbox1"]' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
 }
$my_tabs .= '</ul>';
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();

  echo do_shortcode( $my_tabs );
 ?>
```

UPDATE:

I tried using this code but it does work. Nothing comes through. I don't get any errors but no shortcode is displayed.

```
 <?php 
  $args = array('post_type' => 'services', 'category_name' =>  $childid, 'order_by' => 'the_title', 'order' => 'ASC');   


 // The Query
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 // The Loop
 if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
  $lid = 1;
  $my_tabs .= '<ul class="easybuttons">'; 
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
   $the_query->the_post();
   $my_tabs .= '<li>[su_lightbox type="inline" src="#lightbox' . $lid . '"]' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
   $lid++;
  }
 $my_tabs .= '</ul>';
 }

 echo do_shortcode( $my_tabs );
 wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialise the variable `$my_tabs` somewhere, for instance outside the if block, and increment the lightbox id. You don't need to call `query_posts()`. `order_by` should be `title`, not `the_title`. Make sure `$childid` is definitely a [string of the category slug](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters), **not** the name, if in doubt, take out that parameter altogether to see if you get anything as I imagine this is most likely to be the main issue.

```php
$args = array('post_type' => 'services', 'category_name' =>  $childid, 'order_by' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC');

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$my_tabs = '';

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
 $lid = 1;
 $my_tabs .= '<ul class="easybuttons">'; 
 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
  $the_query->the_post();
  $my_tabs .= '<li>[su_lightbox type="inline" src="#lightbox' . $lid . '"]' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
  $lid++;
 }
$my_tabs .= '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Yea I do! That was actually my next challenge! I will try this!

Comment: This new query comes up with no results. Hmm

Comment: @user2593040 See my updated answer. If it still doesn't work, try var_dump($the_query), to see what comes out

Comment: @user2593040 And have you tried removing `'category_name' =>  $childid` from the arguments? If so, could you post that vardump? Something in the query is resulting in no posts being displayed, and this is my best guess.